# multi step form retrieve data from step 1 to step2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Beginner in jquery ajax. I would like to retrieve datas (this part of the job is done and ok) AND to pass them from step1 to step2 of my form.

My code for the moment is : I've tried to show with #step2 #check-ok the place where I want my datas after phase1 display none and phase2 appear  but not working : my datas stay on step1.

```
   $(".open1").click(function() {
      if (v.form()) {
        var data = {
        'civility'   : jQuery("input[name=civility]:checked", "#to-bc-clt").val(),
        'society'    : jQuery('#society').val(),
        'firstName'  : jQuery('#firstName').val(),
        'lastName'   : jQuery('#lastName').val(),
        'email'      : jQuery('#email').val(),
        };

    jQuery.ajax({
    url : '/mySite/VerifRep/parsers/check.php',
    method : 'POST',
    type    : 'POST',
    data : data,


    success : function(data){
      if (data != 'passed') {
        jQuery('#messages-errors').html(data);
        }  
      if (data == 'passed') {
        $(".frm").hide("fast");
        $("#step2").show("slow");
        $(".open1").css("display","none");
        $(".open2").css("display","inline-block");

         $("#step 2 #check-ok").val(data);
         // Try that way too but not work --> $("#check-ok").html(data);

        }
    },
    error : function(){
        alert('Something wrong.'); }
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: $("#step2 #check-ok").val(data); val function used to assigned the value of form input . also you used space between step and 2 please check it also. check-ok is id so you use directly instead of using parent div id. that means $('#check-ok')  is enough

Comment: Thank to response. #step 2 --> Mistake when I wrote my message (#step2 in my code) but just with '#check-ok' it isn't working.... It's work on phase 1 and I want message on phase 2. I mean my message is on the phase1 and I would like to have it on phase2

Comment: please confirm wheather #check-ok is div tag or form element tag. could you please check the console of your browser any issue raised or not?

Comment: Perhaps I have to 'store' my datas and to code them in the othier step ? but how ?

Comment: use separate div's <div id="first"></div><div id="second"></div> what action made in and got response  displayed in second div use $('#second').html(data)  where data is response from ajax request. try to check $('#second').append(data) also

Comment: stange --> I've just '#check-ok' in my code and response from the console is passed<div id="step2 #check-ok">Test return </div>

Comment: just type $('#check-ok').html() in browser console. what data will be return? please post it

Comment: Sorry for my last msg  --> beginner error.  '<div id="step1"></div><div id="step2"><div id="#check-ok">Test Response</div><div>'; It's the same....  message in first step  not in the second

Comment: Test in reality with true message I want. Console ->"$clt_civil $clt_name : identified" .. Don't retrieve my data. And msg always in phase 1

Comment: I can retrieve my data but impossible to see the response on phase 2 , it stay on phase 1 and stop the multiphase process

Comment: @PHP developper - My console return my message string with the retrieve data  but in the page, not in phase2 ....

Comment: please check the id you have to use more than one time #check-ok

Comment: the id I'have by return you mean ? If it's what you mean. Id is OK all my return datas are ok but just don't pass in step2  and My echo json is visible ....

Comment: i've prepare two string response distinct , one for the check'ok div and an other on for the input hiden. As the echo json is visible I can see I retrieve my data but in phase1  stopping the multiphase process. My English is not fluent fluent, I hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON to store the details locally similar to session of php
I also had the same problem
I had multiple step form and wanted details of step 1 ( plan choices of member ) and use them in function and calculate result and display it in 3rd step where payment was to be done ( cost the plan chosen by that member )

Form should have method POST ( if you use GET , replace POST in php file with GET)

In first step ,
use JSON like

```
var x = document.getElementByName(name_of_textbox_which_has_name);
var y = document.getElementByName(name_of_textbox_which_has_age);
var z = document.getElementByName(name_of_textbox_which_has_city);

var val = {name: x, age: y, city: z};
var toBeSent = JSON.stringify(val);
window.location = "phpfilename.php?xyzvar=" + toBeSent;
```

Put this in a function and call it when user clicks on "Next" button ...

Now , before coming to 2nd step ...
In php file ( phpfilename.php )
Remember the variable name was "xyzvar"

```
<?php
$name=$_POST['xyzvar'];
$data=json_decode($name);
echo $data->name //  prints x ( name entered in textbox )
echo $data->age //  prints y ( age entered in textbox )
echo $data->city //  prints z ( city entered in textbox )
// instead of echo you can use it anywhere for further coding
?>
```